# Rails + Jquery + How to get the checked checkbox values in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

I have checkboxes in a loop.

for example..

```
<% (1..5).each do |chk| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'chk',"#{chk}", :checked=>false %>
<% end %>
```

I want to get the check box id's which are all checked.

Please help me to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want to get this value, on the client side or on the server side after form is submitted?

Comment: jquery method is fine.

Comment: Hey @poojaagarwal : Is this correct - for what you are looking ?

Comment: @Rubyist i want the checkbox ids like chk_1,chk_3

Comment: have a look at updated answer ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jquery Link :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Try this:

**HTML Code :**

```
<input id="chk_1" name="foo" type="checkbox" value="1" />chk1
<input id="chk_2" name="foo" type="checkbox" value="2" />chk2
<input id="chk_3" name="foo" type="checkbox" value="3" />ckh3
<input id="chk_4" name="foo" type="checkbox" value="4" />chk4
<input id="chk_5" name="foo" type="checkbox" value="5" />chk5
<button>Alert List</button>
```

**JsCode :**

```
(function( $ ){
      $.fn.valList = function(){
            return $.map( this, function (elem) {
                  return elem.value || "";
            }).join( "," );
      };
      $.fn.idList = function(){
            return $.map( this, function (elem) {
                  return elem.id || "";
            }).join( "," );
      };
})( jQuery );

$('button').click(function(){
    alert($("input:checked").valList()); 
    alert($("input:checked").idList()); 

});
```

**Running Example**  : [JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dY93b/289/)

Comment: `$("input[type='checkbox']").val();` will only return the value of the first checked box.

Comment: @Rubyist which jquery should i use?

Comment: Jquery 1.11.0 with migrate file. Link is present in above answer.

Comment: if i use $("input[type='checkbox']").val(); its returning "on"

Comment: @BroiSatse : Buddy I have to take a look on your suggestion.

Comment: @Rubyist erase the whole answer and paste only the answer which u have sent on chat

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
<% (1..5).each do |chk| %>
   <%= check_box_tag 'chk[]',"#{chk}", :checked=>false%>
<% end %>
```

Then, in the controller, `params[:chk]` will give you an array of check box values which are checked.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I want a jquery method.

Comment: That you must have said before in your question. Why downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Try This It  may helps you

**Ruby syntax:**

```
 <% (1..5).each do |chk| %>
         <%= check_box_tag('chk[]', chk) %>
         <%= chk %>
      <% end %>
```

**Jquery Syntax:**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('input["name=chk[]"]').change(function(){
     if($(this).attr("checked")){
    alert($(this).val())}
  })
})
```

which gives alert of the checked check box value when you change checkbox.

if you want checked check box value when document loads then try this

```
$('document').ready(function(){
           alert($('input["name=chk[]"]:checked').val())
   })
```